# cuda threads in a loop

Tags: multithreading, loops, cuda

this is a very general question and if someone has any experience with this would be great.

Every time (in a kernel) I want to use threads in a while loop, like this for example:

```
tidx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
tidy = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;

while(i<70) {
    if (tidx<640 && tidy<480){
        //calculations to get a desired array
    }
}
```

my program freezes.

I have tried several things like changing while to for but nothing seems to work.

I'm starting to think that it's just not possible to use threads like that.
Is that true and if not what are the prerequisites?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you modifying i inside the loop? If not, then there's your problem.

Comment: Are you sure that `i` is not always under 70 and running it in an infinite loop ?

Comment: Thanks for replying! Since I understand that this can be done let me be a little bit clearer. the while has a format of while(changes && iterations<200) which changes is boolean and is modified inside the loop and iterations is being modified inside the loop like iterations++. But if the program runs correctly after 70 iterations changes becomes false and that's why i put 70 at my original post.

Comment: code too general to expose the problem

Comment: By "freeze" do you mean the program is not responding, but is still running, or that the program actually crashed? If it crashed and you're using Windows, did you get a message about Windows resetting the video driver?

Comment: I'm using linux and the program doesn't crash. The terminal responds to ctrl+c, it just looks like it's in an endless loop and I can't understand why

Answer (score 2):

All versions of CUDA and all CUDA devices should be able to do loops. Make sure you didn't program an infinite loop or the calculation time just takes relay long.